# html label radio works on desktop and emulator but not iOS Safari

Tags: html, css, mobile, vue.js

I am having a hard time debugging this but basically I have a bunch of check boxes that all look like the following example:

```
<div class="column">
  <input id="radio-10" type="radio" class="radio-custom" value="3">
  <label for="radio-10" class="radio-custom-label"><br>
  <p>Long time employed by the same employer</p></label>
</div>
```

In the emulator in Chrome if I click it, it works fine. On desktop if I click it it works fine (box gets checked). On an actual iphone, you the check box never gets check.

Anything stand out here? Or similar issues.

Also not sure if it matters (since it works on desktop and the emulator but not mobile) These are all created dynamically with vue.js like so:

```
<li v-for="(question, questionIndex) in questions">
                        <h2>{{ question.question }}</h2>

                        <div class="columns">

                          <div class="column" v-for="(answer, index) in question.answers">
                            <input 
                                :id=" 'radio-' + answer.id" 
                                :value='answer.points' 
                                class="radio-custom"  
                                v-model.number="chosen[ questionIndex ]" 
                                type="radio"
                            >
                            <label :for=" 'radio-'+ answer.id" class="radio-custom-label"><br><p>{{ answer.answer }}</p></label>
                          </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="control is-grouped">
                            <p class="control">
                                <button class="button is-primary" 
                                        v-if="questionIndex != 0" 
                                        @click.prevent="back">
                                        Back
                                </button>
                            </p>

                            <p class="control">
                                <button class="button is-primary" 
                                        @click.prevent="next">
                                        Next
                                </button>
                            </p>

                        </div>

                    </li>
```

Update:

I removed the opacity on the acutal radio button and can see it IS WORKING, the css though is not adding the checkmark. Specifically these lines it looks like:

```
 `.radio-custom:checked + .radio-custom-label:before {
    content: "\f00c";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    color: $green;
    font-size: 25px;
}
`
```

Full CSS

```
.checkbox-custom, .radio-custom {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;   
}

.checkbox-custom, .checkbox-custom-label, .radio-custom, .radio-custom-label {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox-custom-label, .radio-custom-label {
    position: relative;
}

.checkbox-custom + .checkbox-custom-label:before, .radio-custom + .radio-custom-label:before {
    content: '';
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.checkbox-custom:checked + .checkbox-custom-label:before {
    content: "\f00c";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    background: rebeccapurple;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.radio-custom + .radio-custom-label:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.radio-custom:checked + .radio-custom-label:before {
    content: "\f00c";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    color: $green;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.checkbox-custom:focus + .checkbox-custom-label, .radio-custom:focus + .radio-custom-label {
  outline: 1px solid #ddd; /* focus style */
}
```

Comment: What happens if you add a `key` attribute to your `li` element like `:key="questionIndex"`?

Comment: Nothing. I was reading about iOS 9 having a element inside label makes it not work but that did nothing either. Again it seems to be an iOS Mobile issue only

Comment: Do the radio buttons here work from your iPhone?
https://jsfiddle.net/bwcat0eg/2/
I notice, by the way, that you have no `name` attribute on your radio buttons.

Comment: @RoyJ Yes it does. I updated my questions since it seems to be CSS related in the radio buttons are working but not reflecting the check

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours of nonsence I found out it was missing the FontAwsome fonts. I have them locally so that is why it was only on mobile.